# ¿Como renderizar en React varios componentes iguales pero que puedan ser identificados?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Digamos que quiero renderizar en un caja `<Box />` 9 "Fichas" iguales con el nombre de  `<Card />`

Entonces hago lo siguiente:

```js
export default class Box extends React.Component {

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="box">
               <Card />
               <Card />
               <Card />

               <Card />
               <Card />
               <Card />

               <Card />
               <Card />
               <Card />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```js
export default class Card extends React.Component{
    
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <button className="card">Soy la carta nº{this.props.dibujo}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es escuchar un evento de click en las fichas. El problema viene cuando quiero que cada ficha sea identificada. Es decir, si pulso en la tercera ficha, quiero que React sepa exactamente que ficha he clickado. Para así poder cambiar su estilo sólo a esa.

En Javascript normal lo que haría sería con el DOM hacer una simple función dónde uso `createElement` y darle un argumento que serviría como identificador (por ejemplo). Sin embargo todavía no conozco mucho React y no me hago la idea como se haría algo así en este caso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A un componente de React le puedes enviar cualquier atributo HTML que quieras, (incluso los data-), entonces a cada uno le podrías pasar un id con el que los puedas identificar.

Posteriormente debes definir en **Card** una propiedad que te sirva de callback y que al capturar el evento click puedas obtener el id desde event.currentTarget, tendrías que hacer algo así:

```js
import React from "react";

export default class Card extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const { id, onClickFicha } = this.props;

        return (
            <div id={id} onClick={onClickFicha}>
                <button className="card">Soy la carta nº{this.props.dibujo}</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default class Box extends React.Component {

    onClickFicha = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        // Obtener el id del elemento donde se hizo click
        const id = event.currentTarget.id;

        // Hacer algo...
        alert("has pulsado " + id);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="box">
                <Card id={1} onClickFicha={this.onClickFicha} />
                <Card id={2} onClickFicha={this.onClickFicha} />
                <Card id={3} onClickFicha={this.onClickFicha} />

                <Card id={4} onClickFicha={this.onClickFicha} />
                <Card id={5} onClickFicha={this.onClickFicha} />
                <Card id={6} onClickFicha={this.onClickFicha} />

                <Card id={7} onClickFicha={this.onClickFicha} />
                <Card id={8} onClickFicha={this.onClickFicha} />
                <Card id={9} onClickFicha={this.onClickFicha} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

He actualizado el ejemplo con la corrección en la asociación del evento click. Para efectos de demostración ambos componentes se encuentran en un mismo archivo, pero deberían estar en archivos aparte como lo tienes actualemente en tu repositorio.

Comment: ¿O sea que el id que le pasas es como un id de HTML? Entonces es más fácil de lo que imaginaba! Por cierto, acaso tengo que bindear el método arriba o algo? Lo digo porque he probado tu código y parece que no atrapa el evento onClick. Le he puesto un console.log(id) dentro para comprobar que funcionase y no aparece nada. Tampoco ningun error, eso sí.

Comment: Ah que pena, es que el evento onClick se debe asociar a un elemento HTML, ¿me puedes actualizar la pregunta con la definición de `<Card />`?, para mostrarte como se hace la asociación

Comment: Lo acabo de hacer. Igualmente te paso un repo online por si te resulta más facil ver el código completo: https://codesandbox.io/s/fervent-stonebraker-gsopu?fontsize=14

Comment: Vale, edité mi respuesta tomando el ejemplo de tu repositorio.

Comment: Creo que ya lo tengo. Me valió esto amigo onClick={this.props.onClick}. Edito, claro también me faltaba el id. Muchas gracias

Comment: ah ok, tomaste la propiedad onClick, también es una opción, pero es buena idea que siempre le des un nombre más descriptivo a este tipo de propiedades que se tratan de callbacks. pero si, también sirve así. Saludos.